# How to download and install chrome browser with specific version in terminal?

Tags: centos, command-line, chrome

I want to download chrome browser version 51 or below through terminal; however the latest version is 58.

Linux: **centOS**

Comment: How special should they be? What OS are you on? What tools did you want to use?

Comment: Linux centOS (using Amazon AMI)

Comment: I want to install chrome version 51 through terminal

Comment: I haven't managed to successfully install it, but you might find a specific version here : https://rpm.pkgs.org/universal/google-chrome-x86_64/google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.119-1.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 16):

Took a little digging, but just pieced this together:

```
yum install -y https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-${GOOGLE_CHROME_VERSION}-1.x86_64.rpm
```

You can extract available versions from the following URL: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable

Comment: After searching for 1 hour, this one finally worked. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 10):

You should search a downloadable link for that version and use `wget` and `yum` or `dpkg` to install..
One source I found is [here](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php) but they don't have the CentOs version.

The official and current version can be found here :

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: This only gives the current version. The question asks how to get any version.

Comment: I agree this is the wrong answer.... but I used it anyway thanks Mazs!

Answer (score 4):

**Download  Google Chrome**

```
wget http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/google/google-chrome-stable-51.0.2704.106-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**Install**

```
rpm -ivh google-chrome-stable-51.0.2704.106-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: This is just as random as "find the software version you want, download it and install through package management"... It applies to Windows as well

Comment: @user34720 I got a `sha256sum` on one of versions provided there (87.0.4280.88), and compared it against Google's official RPM. They were the same. No worries (at least on this version).

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the link shared below. Find and download the rpm file for the specific google chrome version. You can use wget to download it. Just copy the download link URL and pass it as an argument to the wget command.

`http://dist.control.lth.se/public/CentOS-7/x86_64/google.x86_64/Packages/`

- Then use yum to install google chrome from that local rpm file.

`yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm`

Comment: Unfortunately, new versions does not appear to be added for a while.